# Reverse linked list using double pointer

Tags: c++, reverse, singly-linked-list

How to reverse linked list using double pointer?

I was learning about double pointers and thought if we can reverse linked list using one pointer only.

Comment: By "double pointer" do you mean a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-Node (e.g. `Node **`) or do you mean having two pointer values (`Node *`) per Node object?

Comment: pointer to pointer

Comment: Singly linked list or doubly-linked?

Comment: One important lesson to learn about pointers-to-pointers is to not use them. (They are used more often than they should. As in they are used and rarely should be.) Did your lessons get this far? :)

Comment: If the linked list is singly linked then you can't iterate backward. The current node only knows about the next node. It doesn't have any information to tell it where the previous node just was.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to using a pointer to pointer left as an exercise for the reader. Also has some distinct shortcomings in terms of style.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node { 
    int data;
    node *next;
};

node *reverse(node *list) { 
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next;

    while (list) {
        next = list->next;
        list->next = prev;
        prev = list;
        list = next;
    }
    return prev;
}

void show_list(node *list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        std::cout << list->data << ", ";
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *list = NULL;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        node *n = new node;
        n->next = list;
        n->data = i;
        list = n;
    }

    std::cout << "As built: ";
    show_list(list);

    list = reverse(list);

    std::cout << "Reversed: ";
    show_list(list);
    return 0;
}
```

If you decide to modify a pointer you received as a parameter, it's probably easier to deal with a reference to a pointer than a pointer to a pointer though.